# I need help creating a Rectangle class with private instance variables, but public methods and constructors

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, instance-variables

I'm new to using java and I need to make a class called Rectangle, but the code I'm using doesn't seem to work, and the notes for class aren't helpful. I feel like it has something to do with my methods because I don't understand those too well.

The class needs to follow these requirements:
Create a class called rectangle with the following instance variables and public constructors:

- width, double
- height, double
- a constructor with one parameter (double) called sideLength, which sets both the width and height to sideLength.
- a constructor with two parameters width and height (double), which sets both the width and height to the corresponding values that are passed on.
- a public method computeArea with no parameters that returns the area of Rectangle as a double
- a public method computePerimeter with no parameters that returns the perimeter of Rectangle as a double
- a public method getHeight with no parameters that returns the height of Rectangle as a double
- a public method getWidth with no parameters that returns the width of Rectangle as a double

I don't need to make a main method because that was already provided.

This is the code that I'm using, but I keep getting an error that says height cannot be found from the computeArea method and down.

```
 class Rectangle{
     
     private static double width;
     private static double heigth;
     
     public Rectangle(double sideLength) {
         
         Rectangle width = new Rectangle(sideLength);
         Rectangle height = new Rectangle(sideLength);
     }
         
     public Rectangle(double width, double height){
         width = width;
         height = height;
     }    

     public double computeArea() {
         return height * width;
     }
         
     public double computePerimeter() {
         return 2 * (height + width);
     }
         
     public double getHeight() {
         return height;
     }
     
     public double getWidth() {
         return width;
     }
     
 }
```

Comment: Your code should throw `StackOverflowError`. Why are calling `new Rectangle` inside the same constructor? `height` and `width` should not be static. Also, in your second constructor, it should be `this.width = width` and `this.height = height`.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to java, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. I'm trying to follow the notes my professor gave us, but they weren't too helpful. I thought calling new Rectangle would be the thing to use according to the notes given.

Comment: computeArea has "height" but the class has "heigth". That's why it won't compile.

Comment: @codebrane Can you explain more about what you mean about it not compiling?

Comment: If your professor's notes aren't helping you, you're probably best off searching for a textbook (either physical or digital) or an online tutorial. Oracle has some free ones, though I can't comment on their quality: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: “I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing” is not an excuse. If you don’t know what `static` means, don’t add it to the code. And even without knowing anything about Java, just read your line from the constructor aloud: “width = new Rectangle” and you should realize how odd that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the private variables static or they will be shared by all instances of Rectangle.

```
class Rectangle{
     
     private double width;
     private double height;
     
     public Rectangle(double sideLength) {
         
         this.width = sideLength;
         this.height = sideLength;
     }
         
     public Rectangle(double width, double height){
         this.width = width;
         this.height = height;
     }    

     public double computeArea() {
         return height * width;
     }
         
     public double computePerimeter() {
         return 2 * (height + width);
     }
         
     public double getHeight() {
         return height;
     }
     
     public double getWidth() {
         return width;
     }
 }
```

To use it in other code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle square = new Rectangle(1.0);
    double area = square.computeArea();
    System.out.println(area);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(1.0, 2.0);
    area = rectangle.computeArea();
    System.out.println(area);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code that you put, but I'm still getting the error "cannot find symbol: height" like I was before.

Comment: I've added the test code. I've verified it works. You need to put the Rectangle code in a Rectangle.java file and the test code in a Test.java file.

Comment: I have realized that when I used your code, I made a spelling error, but this did work once I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I keep getting an error that says height cannot be found from the computeArea method and down. ..."*

This is because *height* is declared as *[static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)*, thus cannot be accessed from the *non-static*, *instance* method.

```java
class Rectangle {
    double width, height;

    Rectangle(double sideLength) {
        width = height = sideLength;
    }

    Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double computeArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double computePerimeter() {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
}
```

Alternately, use a *[record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/records.html)*.

```java
record Rectangle(double width, double height) {
    Rectangle(double sideLength) {
        this(sideLength, sideLength);
    }
    
    public double computeArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
    
    public double computePerimeter() {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }
}
```